# Storage Image Not Show In Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I'm working with Laravel 9 and I have an image at the this directory:

```
projectname/storage/app/dist/captcha/127.0.0.1/0captcha.png
```

And now I need to load this image at the Blade:

```
<img src="{{ asset("/storage/dist/captcha/".$ip."/0captcha.png") }}">
```

But the image does not show!

And when I look for `asset("/storage/dist/captcha/".$ip."/0captcha.png")` to check what it returns, it prints:

`http://localhost:8000/storage/dist/captcha/127.0.0.1/0captcha.png`

So what's going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

**Note** that I have already ran `php artisan storage:link` and the [C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\public\storage] link already exists.

Comment: The storage link links to `storage/app/public", only that folder is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### STEPS

1. Set up your `dist` filesystem disk in the configuration file: `config/filesystems.php`

```php
<?php

return [

    // ...

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been set up for each driver as an example of the required values.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        // ...

        'dist' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/dist'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage/app/dist',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        // ...

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Symbolic Links
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
    | `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
    | the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
    |
    */

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
        public_path('storage/dist') => storage_path('app/dist'),
    ],

];
```

2. Run the command: `php artisan storage:link` again to set up the new extra `dist` symbolic link.

```
$ php artisan storage:link

   ERROR  The [C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\public\storage] link already exists.

   INFO  The [C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\public\storage/dist] link has been connected to [C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\storage\app/dist].
```

3. Access your assets in the View as usual:

```php
<img src="{{ asset("/storage/dist/captcha/".$ip."/0captcha.png") }}">
```

Comment: I tried your steps but when I run `php artisan storage:link`, it says **`ERROR  The [C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\root\public\storage] link already exists.
`**

Comment: It does not connect the `storage/dist`

Comment: @Pouya Did you configure `public_path('storage/dist') => storage_path('app/dist'),` in the `'links'` array of `config/filesystems.php` ? Please, inspect my configurations closely without skipping a thing.

Comment: Now fixed! I forgot the `public_path('storage/dist') => storage_path('app/dist'),` part. Thanks anyway :)